# UPPER Case issue postgreSQL when importing from text file

Tags: postgresql

I have ruby and rails app, and I have cron task to download text file and import it to the database using

```
\copy hotels FROM 'db/ActivePropertyList.txt' DELIMITER '|'
```

There is a header field which is called EANHotelID in this text file. My import fails because of this particular filed and if I manually rename it to, for example hotel_id, then import goes OK.

Is there any way to overcome this issue because I will be unable to rename it every time manually?

In my database schema the column is called ean_hotel_id.

UPDATE
**Error Description:**

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: COPY "hotels" ("","sequence_number","name","address1","addre...
```

**Text file example**

```
EANHotelId|SequenceNumber|Name|Address1|Address2|City|StateProvince|PostalCode|Country|Latitude|Longitude|AirportCode|PropertyCategory|PropertyCurrency|StarRating|Confidence|SupplierType|Location|ChainCodeID|RegionID|HighRate|LowRate|CheckInTime|CheckOutTime
180997|1|Bristol Metropolitan|Av. Getulio Vargas, 286 - Savassi||Belo Horizonte||30112-020|BR|-19.93301|-43.92641|CNF|1|BRL|.0|52|ESR|Near Liberdade Square||577|90|54||
183714|1|Ibis Vitoria Praia Do Canto|R Joao Da Cruz 385 Praia Do||Vitoria||29055-620|BR|-20.29412|-40.29437|VIX|1|||43|ESR||2141|3711|96.4557|95.4557|12:00 PM|12:00 PM
```

**Table definition**

```
  t.column :ean_hotel_id,         "int"
  t.column :sequence_number,      "int"
  t.column :name,                 "varchar(70)"
  t.column :address1,             "varchar(50)"
  t.column :address2,             "varchar(50)"
  t.column :city,                 "varchar(50)"
  t.column :state_province,       "varchar(2)"
  t.column :postal_code,          "varchar(15)"
  t.column :country,              "varchar(2)"
  t.column :latitude,             "numeric(8,5)"
  t.column :longitude,            "numeric(8,5)"
  t.column :airport_code,         "varchar(3)"
  t.column :property_category,    "int"
  t.column :property_currency,    "varchar(3)"
  t.column :star_rating,          "numeric(2,1)"
  t.column :confidence,           "int"
  t.column :supplier_type,        "varchar(3)"
  t.column :location,             "varchar(80)"
  t.column :chain_code_id,        "varchar(5)"
  t.column :region_id,            "int"
  t.column :high_rate,            "numeric(19,4)"
  t.column :low_rate,             "numeric(19,4)"
  t.column :check_in_time,        "varchar(10)"
  t.column :check_out_time,       "varchar(10)"
```

For COPY I use gem postgres-copy (https://github.com/diogob/postgres-copy). in my task I have the code to map table columns names in the file to the database

```
Hotel.pg_copy_from('db/ActivePropertyList.txt', :delimiter => '|', 
:map => {'EANHotelID' => 'ean_hotel_id',
    'SequenceNumber' => 'sequence_number',
    'Name' => 'name'
     .......
```

Comment: Could you present here the first three rows of your file, the error code and maybe the table definition?

Comment: As you can see all fields pass normally except EANHotelId

Comment: If I open the text file and replace EANHotelId with anything in lower case, and do so in my cron task, COPY proceed well, but I need to do this automatically because database should be renewed at least several times a month

Comment: Have you tried using "with csv header delimiter..."??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Divide the CSV file to determine which string causes the error.
2. Check that issue is not related to 'postgres-copy'

   ```
   cat import.csv | \
     psql -U foo -d bar -c "COPY your_tbl FROM STDIN DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;"
   ```
3. Preprocess the CSV file with `sed` or `awk`, or fix `postgres-copy.`

Comment: From this: `COPY "hotels" ("","sequence_number"...` it looks like that the problem is in the column mapping.

Comment: Yes, I found a solution. The text file was in UTF-8, so it added invisible special character in the beginning of the text file, so replacement didn't work. I just wrote a script to delete this symbol and pg-copy worked well, but maybe it is not good practice and I should convert it somehow (for example using iconv)